# Bounded operator are always unbounded?

Tags: functional-analysis

I saw on wiki that an unbounded operator $X\to Y$ is an operator defined on a subsepace $U$ of $X$, i.e. an operator $U\to Y$. But since $X$ is a subspace of $X$, all bounded operator (i.e. continuous) on $X$ are unbounded, no ? What's the definition for such operator, isn't it weird ? Why didn't they choose an other name ?

[here the link to wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator)

Answer (score 6):

You should think of the theory of unbounded operators as an extension of the theory of bounded operators. Arguably the term "*not necessarily bounded operators*" would fit better and avoid your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In operator theory boundedness is never used in the usual sense! An unbounded operator is one which is not a bounded operator and it may not even be defined on the whole space. In fact when we say $T$ is unbounded operator on $X$ the domain of $T$ need not be $X$!

Comment: I understood that. But it's not written that $U$ has to proper subspace of $X$. So technically, a continuous operator $X\to Y$ is bounded (since continuous) and unbounded (since defined on a subspace of $X$ since $X$ is a subspace of $X$). Isn't it weird ?

Comment: Probabilists say weak convergence for weak$^{*}$ convergence. Most Mathematicians say increasing for non-decreasing. Yes, they are there and we have to live with them.